# SQL insert, update and delete queries in Apache Ignite

Tags: gridgain, ignite

Is SQL Insert, Update and Delete query support available in Apache Ignite 1.7.0 released on 2016-08-05? If not then how can we implement same? or where can I find patch for same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently DML is not supported in Ignite. It will be one of the new features of 1.8. At this stage the alternative is to use GET/PUT to access data in cache.

Comment: Is there any temporary patch that I can get?